# Specify app in: heroku run:detached rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, migration, rake, production

I am trying migrate my production database:

`heroku run:detached --app APP rake db:migrate`

But then heroku says:

`!    No app specified.`

`!    Run this command from an app folder or specify which app to use with --app APP.`

But i am already giving an --app

Anyone an idea how to fix it?

Thanks

Kai

Comment: what about: heroku run rake db:migrate --app APP

Comment: `heroku run rake db:migrate --app APP` it wil recognize the app but it wil say `Error:       Operation timed out - connect(2) (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)`

Comment: have you checked status and logs:  heroku logs --app APP, heroku pg:info --app APP (if using postgresql)

Comment: `heroku run:detached rake db:migrate --app APP` gives the `no app specified`

Comment: `heroku logs --app APP` gives:

Comment: `2014-02-21T14:55:44.995055+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by kaibakker@gmail.com
2014-02-21T14:56:00.584714+00:00 heroku[run.7498]: Awaiting client
2014-02-21T14:56:00.751162+00:00 heroku[run.7498]: State changed from starting to up
2014-02-21T14:56:30.586851+00:00 heroku[run.7498]: Error R13 (Attach error) -> Failed to attach to process
2014-02-21T14:56:31.684124+00:00 heroku[run.7498]: State changed from up to complete`

Comment: `heroku pg:info` doesn't say anything interesting

Comment: does heroku pg:psql --app APP work normal?  Can you connect and query?

Comment: ---> Connecting to HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAROON_URL (DATABASE_URL)
 !    The local psql command could not be located
 !    For help installing psql, see http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-postgresql

Comment: Looks like it is connecting, but i am not an expert ons postgresql